# How to determine whether an NSString is normalized in NFD?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring, normalization, unicode-normalization

I need to determine whether a given NSString is in NFD form. How do i do that?

Context :

The file path I get from Mac OS (in the form of an NSString) is in canonical decomposed form (NFD). This is true especially when the filesystem is HFSPlus.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#CanonicalDecomposition

I need a precomposed string out of this. Now, I want to run the `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` function only if I know that the filename is decomposed in NFD form.

The solution that I could think of:

```
//works on the idea that NFD(NFD(x)) = NFD(x)
BOOL IsCanonicallyDecompsed(NSString *initialFilePath) {
  //decompose the string to NFD form
  NSString *nfdFormOfStr = [initialFilePath decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];
  char *ndfFormUTF8 = [nfdFormOfStr  UTF8String];
  char *intialPathUTF8 = [initialFilePath UTF8String];
  return (strcmp(ndfFormUTF8, intialPathUTF8) == 0);
}
```

Is my solution OK? Also, is my understanding about the filesystem output (in NFD) correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you need a precomposed string (NFC), the simplest and safest thing to do is to always run `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`, regardless of whether the string is NFD or not. For example, it's possible you might get a string where some characters are precomposed and some are decomposed.

Note that the HFS+ filesystem uses a modified version of NFD, where some code-point ranges are kept pre-composed for compatibility with Mac OS 9; I don't know whether the `decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` function uses the same rules as HFS+.